# Run elasticsearch on another java version

Tags: elasticsearch, installation

I have a linux machine with java-9 and java-8 installed on it. I want java-9 to be my default java version but when elasticsearch runs, it should use java-8. Can I do such configuration in elasticsearch startup?

Comment: What about `JAVA_HOME=/pathtoyourjava8jdk elasticsearchBin`

Comment: Not sure whether I got you, I am new to linux